# Tkinter program - errors unable to have a score

Tags: tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and wanted to create a simple program to teach my son to split numbers. When ever my son guesses the right answer the score goes up with one point. When he's wrong the score goes back to 0.
in the code below I'm only able to have score count up when I submit the result of the addition which is not correct. The score should raise if he guesses the "??". Can someone help figure this out please?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Split the Number")
window.geometry("400x300")

# Create the game frame
game_frame = tk.Frame(master=window)
game_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

# Create the number label
number_label = tk.Label(master=game_frame, text="")
number_label.pack()

# Create the result label
result_label = tk.Label(master=game_frame, text="")
result_label.pack()

# Create the entry box
entry = tk.Entry(master=game_frame)
entry.pack()



# Set a new random number
def set_number():
    global score
    number1 = random.randint(1, 5)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 5)
    number_label["text"] = f"{number1} + ?? = {number1 + number2}"
    result_label["text"] = ""

# Create the score label
score = 0
score_label = tk.Label(master=window, text=f"Score: {score}")
score_label.place(anchor="se", relx=1, rely=1)

# Set the initial number
set_number()

# Create the submit button
def submit():
    global score
    # Get the numbers from the label and the guess from the entry box
    numbers = number_label["text"].split(" = ")[1]
    number2 = int(numbers)
    guess = int(entry.get())
    # Check if the guess is correct
    if guess == number2:
        result_label["text"] = "JUIST"
        score += 1
    else:
        result_label["text"] = "FOUT"
    # Update the score label
    score_label["text"] = f"Score: {score}"
    # Clear the entry box and set a new number
    entry.delete(0, "end")
    set_number()

submit_button = tk.Button(master=game_frame, text="Submit", command=submit)
submit_button.pack()

# Run the main loop
window.mainloop()
```

I tried to change the block below but it doesnt count up

```
    if guess == number2:
        result_label["text"] = "JUIST"
        score += 1
```

Comment: solved it by commenting the line and making number1 & number2 global
# number2 = int(numbers)

Answer (score 0):

The condition *guess == number2* is wrong
because *number2* is the sum of two randomly generated numbers

Below is the correct implementation

```
sum = int(number_label["text"].split(" = ")[1])
string_before_equal = number_label["text"].split(" = ")[0]
first_int = int(string_before_equal.split(" + ")[0])
guess = int(entry.get())

# Check if the guess is correct
if guess == sum - first_int:
    result_label["text"] = "JUIST"
    score += 1
```